# cannot cout a string using code blocks

Tags: string, codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks to run this simple code. It gets compiled but when I run it the output window generates an error (aaa.exe has stopped working). aaa is the file name.
What is problem in displaying string using cout?
Everything else is working perfectly like loops, functions, arrays, structures but when I use cout for string, it always generates this error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string a="abc";
cout<<a<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I checked it in Borland 5.5. and GNU GCC compiler. Both face same problem.

Comment: It's working on my system using GCC.

Comment: Have you configured your CodeBlocks installation correctly? Also, why are you saying that the problem is with `cout`? Is it working without that statement?